# svn+ssh checkout slow

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, ssh

I trying to checkout about 400MB of images from svn using svn+ssh.

It is running extremely slow. (approx 3Kbytes/s)

I am using TortoiseSVN as the client.

The server is the standard svn server that comes with ubuntu.

Any ideas how i can debug this.

Comment: I have this same problem with an SVN 1.6 running on a RHEL server using FSFS repository.  I too connect to the repository from TortoiseSVN using svn+ssh url, and I use Pageant to host my SSH key.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing DNS configuration. Set your server ip address as a primary DNS.